# Bit values of x12 and x13 after RISC-V execution + RISC-V compiler?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, endianness, riscv

I'm struggling to understand how RISC-V works so I'm wondering if 1. there's an easy-to-use RISC-V compiler and 2. if anyone would be able to help me walk through this particular snippet of code:

(assume x5 is somewhere on the stack)

```
addi x11, x0, -1261
sw x11, 0(x5)
sw x11, 2(x5)
lb x12, 1(x5)
lbu x13, 2(x5)
```

Comment: what part of the risc-v documentation do you not understand?

Comment: gcc is an easy to use compiler that can target risc-v and is freely and easily available.  this is assembly language so you need an assembler not a compiler and gnu has an assembler that is also easy to use and freely available and can target risc-v

Comment: @old_timer I thought that x11 was storing the 0th bit of x5, then the 2nd, then you load the first bit into x12, and then I wasnt sure about the last line. That being said, I fail to see the significance of the snippet, how are we supposed to know what x5 even is in order to figure out x12 and x13?

Comment: that is an offset not a bit, it is a mips style syntax.  0(x5) means the thing at address value in x5 + 0.  2 means contents at address value in x5 + 2. so if x5 were 0x1000 that would be address at 0x1000 and 0x1002.

Comment: now that is an unaligned access of course, so that is interesting/strange. but you know what x11 is you know what is being stored at x5+0, +2 and then read back from x5+1 and x5+2

Comment: so independent of what x5 is and so long as risc-v is okay with unaligned accesses (I guess it is I have to look that up myself) then you can determine x12 and x13 (so long as you know the endianness for this processor/implementation).

Comment: based on Eriks answer/comments, assuming you knew what x5 was and assuming unsigned access and assuming an endianness, you can determine x12 and x13.  you can simply determine x12 and x13 for little and big and have two answers if you dont know the endianness. (I assume little, but perhaps that is a bad assumption).   As far as alignment issues whoever wrote this code clearly was not concerned about that.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy to use RISC V assembler and simulator called [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/releases/tag/continuous).  It's a java program, that has an integrated IDE, assembler, and simulator with debugger.  So, you can enter this code, and single step to see it execute.

If your computer automatically launches .jar files, then double click it, otherwise the command line java -jar RARSxxx.jar will work.

However, the code sequence you're showing is incomplete: `x5` will need to be initialized with some value before running that or else the first `sw` will fail.  Such initialization may require some data memory also to be part of the program fragment.

Like some other risc machines, RISC V expects align memory accesses.  `0(x5)` and `2(x5)` cannot both be aligned to word boundaries as would be required by `sw`.  So, this code sequence has issues.

Comment: oh ok! can i just put 'add x5, x0, x0' before it to initialize x5 to zero? Also for the command to open the compiler, it says java isn't a command on my terminal?

Comment: Sure, but 0 is an illegal address.

Comment: You have to have java installed to use RARS